# Update SQL column with the varchar data to nvarchar column data

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to save the double byte word in the nvarchar datatype;

My update query as follows :

```
 UPDATE T  
                       SET                  
                           T.[Description]= T1.[Description]                        
                    FROM temple T
                    INNER JOIN temple1 T1 ON T.templeId=T1.templeId
temple1 table columns:

templeid int
description varchar(60)

temple 

templeid int
description nvarchar(200)
```

I have a text some thing like this 'ＧＡＤＥＬＩＵＳ　Ｋ．Ｋ.' in the temple1 table description column I need to update exactly the same in the temple description column
if I use the above update query it's updating like this 'GADELIUS K.K.'

normally for single update I can use N'ＧＡＤＥＬＩＵＳ　Ｋ．Ｋ' it works but I need to dynamically update all the columns.

Comment: what's the difference in the text, other than the font? temple1 table's description column should also by nvarchar.

Comment: it's not only the font but also the space in between the characters is more.

Comment: How so? What I mean is, what is the equivalent Unicode values of each?

Comment: The spacing seems to actually just be an artifact of the font. If you copy those two values into a generic text editor, they're the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it something like below it works :

```
UPDATE T  
                       SET                  
                           T.[Description]= N'' +  T1.[Description]                        
                    FROM temple T
                    INNER JOIN temple1 T1 ON T.templeId=T1.templeId
```